# Geometric sequence for $a$ and $b$

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

$a$, $a^{\log_{10}a}$, $b^{\log_{10}b}$, $(ab)^{\log_{10}(ab)}$ are successive terms of a geometric sequence. Find the values of $a$ and $b$.

What I've tried so far:

$$\frac{a^{\log_{10}a}}{a}=\frac{b^{\log_{10}b}}{a^{\log_{10}a}}=\frac{(ab)^{\log_{10}(ab)}}{b^{\log_{10}b}}$$

But it seems like there's a better solution...

Comment: Does $\lg$ mean $\log_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\log_ca=y\implies a=c^y$ and $\log_cb=x\implies b=c^x$ where $c>0,\ne1$

So, the series becomes $c^y,(c^y)^y=c^{y^2}, (c^x)^x=c^{x^2}, (ab)^{\log ab}=(ab)^{\log a+\log b}=(c^yc^x)^{(x+y)}=c^{(x+y)^2}$

$$\implies \frac{c^{y^2}}{c^y}=\frac{c^{x^2}}{c^{y^2}}=\frac{c^{(x+y)^2}}{c^{x^2}}$$

$$\text{ or,  }c^{y^2-y}=c^{x^2-y^2}=c^{(x+y)^2-x^2}$$

$\implies y^2-y=x^2-y^2=2xy+y^2$ as $(x+y)^2-x^2=2xy+y^2$ and $c>0, \ne1$

So, $y^2-y=2xy+y^2$

$\implies 2xy+y=0, y(2x+1)=0$

Either $y=0\implies x^2=0\iff x=0\implies a=c^0=1,b=c^0=1$

or $2x+1=0\implies x=-\frac12$

Put the value of  $x$ in $y^2-y=x^2-y^2\implies 2y^2-y-\frac14=0,8y^2-8y-1=0$

$y=\frac{8\pm\sqrt{8^2-4(8)(-1)}}{2\cdot8}=\frac{2\pm\sqrt6}{4}$